# PGFplots calculations at coordinates and rescale the axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I need to redraw some plots using PGFplots. For those plots I only have the `eps` file. With Inkscape I could generate a `tex` code and grab the points listed in the MWE. However, in the plot, the `x-axis` ranges from `0,2,...,26` and `y-axis` ranges from `0,2,...16.8`.

Is it possible to do some calculations at coordinates to have the values in that range or just place the appropriate values at axes?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8,compat/show suggested version=false}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    xmin=0,ymin=0,
    %xmax=26,ymax=20,
]
\addplot[color=green,mark=square*] coordinates {%
(58.2500,81.5000) (84.9168,98.8332) (111.5830,114.5830) (138.3330,127.3330) (165.0000,142.7500) (191.7500,153.7500) (218.4170,149.0830) (245.1670,152.8330) (271.8330,160.8330) (298.5830,138.7500) (325.2500,115.0000) (352.0000,91.0832) (378.6670,71.1668) (405.4170,57.3332)
};
\addplot[color=blue,mark=*] coordinates {%
(58.2500,85.4168) (84.9168,106.3330) (111.5830,127.2500) (138.3330,147.0000) (165.0000,174.8330) (191.7500,201.0000) (218.4170,212.6670) (245.1670,229.0830) (271.8330,268.0830) (298.5830,262.5000) (325.2500,238.5000) (352.0000,193.4170) (378.6670,154.0000) (405.4170,121.5830)
};
\addplot[color=red,mark=diamond*] coordinates {%
(58.2500,116.8330) (84.9168,144.7500) (111.5830,169.5000) (138.3330,184.2500) (165.0000,201.0830) (191.7500,208.0000) (218.4170,190.5000) (245.1670,177.3330) (271.8330,174.5830) (298.5830,141.3330) (325.2500,104.5000) (352.0000,79.7500) (378.6670,61.9168) (405.4170,50.6668)
};
\addplot[color=green,mark=square*,dashed] coordinates {%
(58.2500,68.0000) (84.9168,80.0000) (111.5830,91.5000) (138.3330,100.5830) (165.0000,111.8330) (191.7500,119.6670) (218.4170,116.0830) (245.1670,116.9170) (271.8330,120.9170) (298.5830,111.0830) (325.2500,96.3332) (352.0000,77.9168) (378.6670,64.2500) (405.4170,53.0000)
};
\addplot[color=blue,mark=*,dashed] coordinates {%
(58.2500,70.2500) (84.9168,84.7500) (111.5830,99.9168) (138.3330,114.5000) (165.0000,133.4170) (191.7500,152.5830) (218.4170,158.3330) (245.1670,170.3330) (271.8330,201.6670) (298.5830,194.5000) (325.2500,176.3330) (352.0000,149.5000) (378.6670,123.7500) (405.4170,95.4168)
};
\addplot[color=red,mark=diamond*,dashed] coordinates {%
(58.2500,93.3332) (84.9168,113.7500) (111.5830,128.0830) (138.3330,138.8330) (165.0000,150.6670) (191.7500,155.0000) (218.4170,148.3330) (245.1670,137.0000) (271.8330,134.0830) (298.5830,115.0000) (325.2500,88.6668) (352.0000,69.9168) (378.6670,55.0832) (405.4170,47.0000)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The real plot is below.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do both. In the following example I used

```
xtick=data,
xticklabels={0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26},
```

to explicitly give some labels at the x-axis at the positions determined by the data.

For the y-axis I used a calculation:

```
yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick/10}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}},
```

but I wasn't sure if the transformation of the points was linear or which function was used for the scaling of the points in the first place. I just wanted to illustrate that you can perform calculations using `\tick` (the value used for the labels).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8,compat/show suggested version=false}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    xtick=data,
   xticklabels={0,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16,18,20,22,24,26},
   yticklabel={
  \pgfmathparse{\tick/10}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}},
    xmin=58.25,xmax=405.417,
]
\addplot[color=green,mark=square*] coordinates {%
(58.2500,81.5000) (84.9168,98.8332) (111.5830,114.5830) (138.3330,127.3330) (165.0000,142.7500) (191.7500,153.7500) (218.4170,149.0830) (245.1670,152.8330) (271.8330,160.8330) (298.5830,138.7500) (325.2500,115.0000) (352.0000,91.0832) (378.6670,71.1668) (405.4170,57.3332)
};
\addplot[color=blue,mark=*] coordinates {%
(58.2500,85.4168) (84.9168,106.3330) (111.5830,127.2500) (138.3330,147.0000) (165.0000,174.8330) (191.7500,201.0000) (218.4170,212.6670) (245.1670,229.0830) (271.8330,268.0830) (298.5830,262.5000) (325.2500,238.5000) (352.0000,193.4170) (378.6670,154.0000) (405.4170,121.5830)
};
\addplot[color=red,mark=diamond*] coordinates {%
(58.2500,116.8330) (84.9168,144.7500) (111.5830,169.5000) (138.3330,184.2500) (165.0000,201.0830) (191.7500,208.0000) (218.4170,190.5000) (245.1670,177.3330) (271.8330,174.5830) (298.5830,141.3330) (325.2500,104.5000) (352.0000,79.7500) (378.6670,61.9168) (405.4170,50.6668)
};
\addplot[color=green,mark=square*,dashed] coordinates {%
(58.2500,68.0000) (84.9168,80.0000) (111.5830,91.5000) (138.3330,100.5830) (165.0000,111.8330) (191.7500,119.6670) (218.4170,116.0830) (245.1670,116.9170) (271.8330,120.9170) (298.5830,111.0830) (325.2500,96.3332) (352.0000,77.9168) (378.6670,64.2500) (405.4170,53.0000)
};
\addplot[color=blue,mark=*,dashed] coordinates {%
(58.2500,70.2500) (84.9168,84.7500) (111.5830,99.9168) (138.3330,114.5000) (165.0000,133.4170) (191.7500,152.5830) (218.4170,158.3330) (245.1670,170.3330) (271.8330,201.6670) (298.5830,194.5000) (325.2500,176.3330) (352.0000,149.5000) (378.6670,123.7500) (405.4170,95.4168)
};
\addplot[color=red,mark=diamond*,dashed] coordinates {%
(58.2500,93.3332) (84.9168,113.7500) (111.5830,128.0830) (138.3330,138.8330) (165.0000,150.6670) (191.7500,155.0000) (218.4170,148.3330) (245.1670,137.0000) (271.8330,134.0830) (298.5830,115.0000) (325.2500,88.6668) (352.0000,69.9168) (378.6670,55.0832) (405.4170,47.0000)
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I need to see what is the real transformation. But with your example I know how to scale the axis. :)